# Picker in Forms stops responding to tap gestures if lower priority tap gesture is attached to the Form

Tags: swift, swiftui, picker

All I want is to have I functional `Picker` inside a `Section` in a `Form` with a tap gesture attached to the `Form`.

Consider the following code.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var someText = ""
    @State private var taxPersent = 10.0
    @State private var itemTaxPersent = 10.0
    @FocusState private var isTaxRateFieldIsFocused: Bool
    let newGesture = TapGesture().onEnded {
        print("Tap on Form")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {

            Section {
                TextField("", text: $someText)
                    .focused($isTaxRateFieldIsFocused)
                HStack {
                    Text(TaxRate(rawValue: taxPersent)?.description ?? "Unknown tax")
                    Text("\(itemTaxPersent)")
                }
            }
            
            Section {
                Picker("Tax", selection: $taxPersent) {
                    ForEach(TaxRate.allCases) { tax in
                        Text(tax.description).tag(tax.rawValue)
                    }
                }
                .pickerStyle(.segmented)
                .onChange(of: taxPersent) { newTax in
                    isTaxRateFieldIsFocused = false
                    itemTaxPersent = newTax
                }
            }
            
        }
        .gesture(newGesture)
    }
}
```

I do need to execute `newGestures` action. But I want the tap gesture to also reach the `Picker` and switch it and its underlying value.
But for now only long taps have effects on the `Picker`. Regular tap gestures seem to be intercepted by the `Form` although this is not what I was expecting [from the doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/gesture(_:including:)).

Just to give the ability to reproduce the issue precisely here is the rest of the code used:

```
enum TaxRate: Double, CaseIterable, CustomStringConvertible, Codable, Identifiable {
    case ndsFoodLight = 10.1, ndsFood = 20.0
    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .ndsFoodLight:
            return NSLocalizedString("Tax Food Light", comment: "")
        case .ndsFood:
            return NSLocalizedString("Tax Food", comment: "")
        }
    }
    var id: Self { self }
}
```